# Does SqlCommand with StoredProcedure type provide an outer transaction?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, transactions, sqlcommand

I have this code for invoking a stored procedure:

```
 //SqlConnection connection = ...;

 using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
 {
     command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
     command.CommandText = "usp_MyProc";
     command.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
```

and the stored procedure is as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_MyProc]
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRAN
    -- SOME STATEMENTS IN HERE
COMMIT TRAN
RETURN 0
END
```

Is the transaction controlled by those `BEGIN TRAN` and `COMMIT TRAN` statements or is there an outer transaction somehow induced by the `SqlCommand` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `SqlCommand` does not generate an automatic transaction.

Whether the stored procedure transaction has control depends whether there is already an open transaction at the point when the SQLCommand is executed.

If there is no open transaction, then the `BEGIN TRANS..COMMIT TRANS` in the stored procedure controls the transaction.

Comment: To generate a transaction from .net you can use command.Transaction = transaction; or use transaction scope. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx

Comment: It was not a answer was a comment over the asnwer, in special over the line "A SqlCommand does not generate an automatic transaction" and it was not posted for your sake but for OP and any other people in search of knowledge about SqlCommand and transactions control